# the batch normlization layer do not work (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I implement a network using tensorflow, and the loss is not converged. Then, I get some value in the network, and I find that the BN layer do not work. Please look at the following picture:

[image]

We can see that s2 is the result of batch normalization of s1, but the value in s2 is still very large. I don't know what's the problem. Why the value in s2 is so large?

I have updated my code to [github](https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/DeepRigidRegistration). Someone who is interested can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization),

> when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated.
>   By default the update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so
>   they need to be executed alongside the train_op. Also, be sure to add
>   any batch_normalization ops before getting the update_ops collection.
>   Otherwise, update_ops will be empty, and training/inference will not
>   work properly.

For example:

```
training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name="is_training")
# ...
x_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training)
# ...
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
train_op = tf.group([train_op, update_ops])

# or, you can also do something like this:
# with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
#    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

So, it is really important to get the update ops as stated in the tensorflow documentation because in training time the moving variance and the moving mean of the layer have to be updated. If you don’t do this, batch normalization will not work and the network will not train as expected. It is also useful to declare a placeholder to tell the network if it is in training time or inference time, as during test(or inference) time, the mean and the variance are fixed. They are estimated using the previously calculated means and variances of each training batch.

Comment: Sorry, I have found the reason why BN layer do not work. The reason is that I do not assign the training=True. The default training is False.